# Bluetooth File Transfer for my app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to make an application similar to share it but not so advanced... the main activity.xml have 5 buttons one for application 2 for image 3 for audio 4 for video 5 for docs.
1 will fetch all installed apps on device on list view and then onclick will open native inbuilt bluetooth chooser to pair device and send the file
2 (already did half work) will fetch an image from gallery preview it on image view a button is placed on clicking which will open native bluetooth chooser to pair and send file
3 4 5 all will do similar work

the problem is in button 2 java code

```
public class MainImage extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_main);
        Button sendim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imSend);
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            Bitmap bm = 
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),bmp.getGenerationId());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[]b = baos.toByteArray();

        }
    }



    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }

    public void sendx(View v) {

     }
}
```

how to send the byte stream baos of bmp to sendx method to send it via blueooth

Here is the files help me finishing it suggest something
https://github.com/avd10/bluetoothfiletranferAndroid

Comment: Please don't link to Github and instead please post a [mcve] of the problem with your code. We aren't here to implement a whole feature on your own code

Comment: done.. new to stackoverflow

Comment: You say "button 2" is thy problem, but what is that in your code? And what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you need `sendx`? Is that set in the XML? If so, would b it help if you had set the click listeners in the Java code?

Comment: @cricket_007 The sendx method is set in xml android:onclick........ android:onclick and setonclick listener both will serve the same purpose....

Comment: @cricket_007 regarding button 2... the activity_main.xml contains 5 button no1 for application no 2 for image and so on... i am working with button 2 button2 will navigate to new xml which have a imageview and button and the java file code i posted is of that.. it allows user to select an image from gallery to image view what i want is on sendx is that image selected will be send using bluetooth how to do that.... i have already converted it into bytestream as well as there it is in code

Answer (score 0):

> how to send the byte stream baos of bmp to sendx method to send it via blueooth

How about you store it as a member variable of the class?

```
public class MainImage extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    private Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public void sendx(View v) {
        byte[] toSend = bitmapToBytes(selectedBitmap);
        if (toSend.length != 0) {
            // TODO: Send to bluetooth
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        Button sendim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imSend);
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            selectedImage = data.getData();

            ...

            try {
                selectedBitmap = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
                Log.d("ImageLoader", "image has been loaded!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        } // end request code
    } // end onActivityResult

    private byte[] bitmapToBytes(Bitmap bmp) {
        if (bmp == null) return new byte[]; // empty array
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),bmp.getGenerationId());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```